# Can I delete a user from Google Apps free and then create a mailing list with the same name?

Tags: google-workspace

I created a user on Google Apps (free), then after a while I realised it *may* have made more sense to just create a mailing list with that name.

Can I delete the user and then create a mailing list with the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to do it with a dummy account and it worked.

*However, this does not imply that it would just work with any account of any age or activity.*